Need explanation why this Shröder Bernstein Theorem 'proof' fails
I'm not asking to give sense for famous proofs that no Axiom-of-Choice included like Königs Dedekinds ,(... etc to be discussed in proofwiki.)
I need to know what is off with the following proof attempt per theorem:
For $X,Y$ sets,
$f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $g: Y \rightarrow X$ are injective functions.
Let $S=f(X)$ be a image of $f$ in $Y$.
Assume there exists $w \in Y \backslash S$.Define $h(y)$ to be $f^{-1}(y)$ if $y \in S$ and $g(y)$ if $y \in Y \backslash S$. It is obvious $h$ is injective.
But since $h(f(h(w))) = h(w)$ and by injectivity of $h$ we have $f(h(w))=w$ which negates whole existence for $w$ and $f(X)$ must be equal to $Y$, $f$ must then be a bijection.
Is it cyclic to define $h$ in such way and h being injective fails to hold? Or is it bad to assume $h$ to be restricted into inverse of $f$ because it leans on Axiom-of-Choice? Please do tell.

Why is  it "obvious" that $h$ is injective?  Suppose $X=\mathbb N=Y$ and let $f(n)=2n$, $g(n)=n$.  Then $h(2)=1$, right?  But $h(1)=1$ also.

I'm confused... okay but we still have

Now I noticed that I did nothing but to repeat the sentence $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ over long way around. The counter example was simple yet very concrete. Thank you for your advice.

Take $X=Y=\mathbb{N}$, $f(n)=2n$ and $g(n)=n$. Then $h$ as defined is not injective, since $h(4n+2)=2n+1=h(2n+1)$.
